# WHY! doesn't this dispose of all the objects on the flow panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

WHY! doesn't this dispose of all the objects on the flow panel!?
the count shows 5 and there are 5 buttonsWithProperties on the form, no other objects are on the form.

```
foreach (ButtonWithProperties itemButton in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
        {
            itemButton.Dispose();
        }
```

It disposes 3 of the object but not the last 2...

Comment: Is your ButtonWithProperties class using unmanaged resources? If not, I'm not sure it's really necessary to implement the IDisposable interface, as the GC will automatically clean up your resources when they're no longer needed. If you're trying to do something else, like remove the buttons from the visual tree, there are explicit methods for that.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, the ButtonWithProperties object is just a class with about six get set properties (all strings) which inherits from the class Button.

Comment: Ok, so what are you trying to accomplish by invoking the Dispose method on your buttons?

Comment: Why do you need ButtonWithProperties to implement IEnumerable at all? Just let the garbage collector manage them.

Comment: I create the buttons on the fly based on data returned, when the data changes I wanted to delete all the buttons and then recreate them based on the new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it's a bad practice to `Dispose()` an object to which there is a live reference (in your visual tree). If you want to remove the buttons, you perhaps have to remove them from `Controls` in an orderly way. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.removeat.aspx.

Edit:
Please note that the button is an `IDisposable`, therefore the version with `RemoveAt` needs an explicit `Dispose`:

```
var controls = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls;
for (int i = controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    var c = controls[i];
    if (c is ButtonWithProperties)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.RemoveAt(i);
        c.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Edit:
[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.clear.aspx) suggests that `Dispose` should be called even if one is using `Clear`. So if you don't need the buttons any more, you should `Dispose()` them.

Comment: the remove option behaves the same way it leaves 2 or 3 bof the 5 buttons each time!

Comment: I can't access the link for some reason guess MS are having problems too!

Comment: @Adrian: Just look up "Control.ControlCollection.RemoveAt Method" at MSDN

Comment: @Adrian: could you please post your code with RemoveAt which fails?

Comment: I just tried flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear(); which works fine!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Adrian: beware that `Clear()` will remove all the child controls, not only that of type `ButtonWithProperties`.

Comment: thanks but that ok for me it only has  that type on it...

I found out why its not working i was looping forward 

            for (int i = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count; i > 0; i--)
            {
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.RemoveAt(i-1);
            }

Works can you do a for each backwards!?

Comment: @Adrian: for selective deletion you need something like `for (int i = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) if (flowLayoutPanel1.Controls[i] is ButtonWithProperties) flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.RemoveAt(i);` Note that you need to iterate from the back :-)

Comment: @Adrian: It will work forward with the following code: `for (int i = 0; i < flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count; /* nothing */) if (flowLayoutPanel1.Controls[i] is ButtonWithProperties) flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.RemoveAt(i); else ++i;` Note that deletion shifts the indices :-)

Comment: @Adrian - beware that calling RemoveAt() without calling Dispose() is a unpluggable leak.

Comment: @Hans: Indeed, unlike WPF the WinForms button is IDisposable. I'll add this to the answer, thank you for the hint.